# Vue.js: v-repeat generates 404 console error before successfully fetching data via AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, http-status-code-404, vue.js

I am trying to load some `items` via an AJAX request to my own API and display them on my site with `Vue.js`. It's already working fine and displaying the images with the code below, except the issue that I'm getting a 404 error in the *developer console*:

`GET http://example.com/images/%7B%7B%image_file%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)`

before the XHR request finshes

`XHR finished loading: GET "http://example.com/api/getItems".`

HTML (with blade syntax):

```
<div id="items-wrapper">
    <div v-repeat="items">
       <img src="http://example.com/images/@{{ image_file }}">
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#items-wrapper',

    ready: function() {
        this.fetchItems();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchItems: function() {
            this.$http.get('api/getItems', function(items) {
                this.$set('items', items);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

For me it looks like `<img src="http://example.com/images/@{{ image_file }}">` is rendered before the XHR request finishes and therefor throwing a 404 error.

Any ideas how to avoid the 404 error in the console? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by [@kreitje](https://laracasts.com/@kreitje) from laracasts.com:

From the Vue.js documentation (http://vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-attr)

You should use v-attr instead of mustache binding when setting the src attribute on  elements. Your templates are parsed by the browser before being compiled by Vue.js, so the mustache binding will cause a 404 when the browser tries to fetch it as the image’s URL.

So I changed it to

```
<img v-attr="src: 'http://example.com/images/' + image_file">
```

and it's working perfectly fine.